# ArcGIS ClassBreaksRenderer isMaxInclusive doesn't affect JSON

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, style, json

In using ArcGIS's ClassBreaksRenderer, I've made use of `setMaxInclusive(false)` to allow the breaks to not include the maximum value. This works fine when using the renderer object itself (such as in a Feature Layer). However, when I convert the ClassBreaksRenderer to JSON using the `toJson` function, it does not change the resulting JSON object. I'm using the renderer in a dynamic layer (setting it through LayerDrawingOptions), and when I do that it is being treated as if that property were not set, which affects the resulting image. Looking at the network traffic, I see that it's sending the JSON for the renderer. I've included sample code below based on the ArcGIS renderer_class_breaks sample to give an idea of what I'm talking about.

My question is: is there a way to get JSON for a renderer that includes a reference to the `isMaxInclusive` property, or that behaves in the same way? Or is this just something that was not implemented in JSON?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>Class Breaks Renderer</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.19/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style>
      html, body, #map{
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.19/"></script>
    <script>
      var map;
      require([
        "esri/map", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
        "esri/InfoTemplate", "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol", 
        "esri/renderers/ClassBreaksRenderer",
        "esri/Color", "dojo/dom-style", "dojo/domReady!"
      ], function(
        Map, FeatureLayer,
        InfoTemplate, SimpleFillSymbol, 
        ClassBreaksRenderer,
        Color, domStyle
      ) {
        map = new Map("map", {
          basemap: "streets",
          center: [-98.215, 38.382],
          zoom: 7,
          slider: false
        });

        var symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol();
        symbol.setColor(new Color([150, 150, 150, 0.5]));

        var renderer = new ClassBreaksRenderer(symbol, "POP07_SQMI");
        renderer.addBreak(0, 25, new SimpleFillSymbol().setColor(new Color([56, 168, 0, 0.5])));
        renderer.addBreak(25, 63.4, new SimpleFillSymbol().setColor(new Color([139, 209, 0, 0.5])));
        renderer.addBreak(63.4, 175, new SimpleFillSymbol().setColor(new Color([255, 255, 0, 0.5])));
        renderer.addBreak(175, 400, new SimpleFillSymbol().setColor(new Color([255, 128, 0, 0.5])));
        renderer.addBreak(400, Infinity, new SimpleFillSymbol().setColor(new Color([255, 0, 0, 0.5])));

        // Running with setMaxInclusive(false) turns the block just above the red wichita to yellow
        // Running without it sets it to green
        renderer.setMaxInclusive(false);

        // Neither setting for maxInclusive affects the output of renderer.toJson()
        console.log('renderer.toJson()', renderer.toJson());

        var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("${NAME}", "${*}");
        var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("https://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/3", {
          mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT,
          outFields: ["*"],
          infoTemplate: infoTemplate
        });

        featureLayer.setDefinitionExpression("STATE_NAME = 'Kansas'");
        featureLayer.setRenderer(renderer);
        map.addLayer(featureLayer);
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

it appears that you've caught something that just wasn't implemented in JSON.  i can reproduce the same behavior in version 4.2 of the API and i've notified the development team of the problem.

http://jsbin.com/mimizociju/1/edit?html,output

is there a specific use case that makes it totally infeasible to workaround the issue in your own client code?

Comment: I have a workaround in place now that changes the renderer values to compensate.

Comment: glad to hear it. thanks for taking the time to file the report (and close the loop).

Comment: Would definitely still like it if the JSON had a similar property, though.

Comment: me too. I'll update this thread if/when I get more info.